# Reading out Button State while waiting

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have a small beginner question :D. I want to make the raspberry Pi sleep for 5 seconds and in this time i want him to check the status of a button and if the button is pressed he quits the waiting status imediatlly and continues with other stuff. 
I tried it with time.sleep(5) but in this case he sleeps for 5 Seconds and does nothing. I also tried time_a = time.time() and then substract it but in this case my thonny python ide crashed for some reason... 


Thank you for the Help!

Comment: Post the code that you tried using time (in code block) and any error message.

Comment: @CoderMike there were no error messages my IDE only showed the Outputs at the end of the programm therefore i thought that it didn t work but now i guess it does

Comment: Make sure you have at least a small sleep somewhere in your loop eg time.sleep(0.1) otherwise you may see 100% cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

Solution i guess: My IDE was to slow to print out that it was working. I tried the programm in the shell and there i saw the expected result. I did it with `timer_a = time.time()` and `elapsed = time.time()-timer_a`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.